# Foreach to for List objects

Tags: c#

```
foreach (Question question in Holder.Questions)
{
 //...
}
```

Holder.cs:
Holder containts a list of Question objects

```
public List<Question> Questions{ get; set; }
```

Question.cs:
The Question class holds several attributes such as name, date, etc...

The problem with the foreach i am adding for every question, but i want to add something seperate to a question.

How would i be able to acces the question object in the following class?
The holder is already filled up with values of the current holder object.

In other words how do i work with the question. .... without the foreach loop? 
Cause i am getting the same error all the time that question is actually empty or null (object not set on a reference, ....)

Not really sure how to acces this question. without the foreach loop in this context!
Some examples would prove very handy! Thanks.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.

Comment: Seems like your `SaveEnquete` method loads the xml file, finds the current enquete node and than adds *all* questions to the node. What you actually want is to add only the last question (as you call the method after each question added). You could alter the method to accept both an `Enquete` and a `Vraag` object. Find the enquete node in the xml and add the vraag to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constructor of the Holder class make sure to initalize the Questions list object.

```
this.Questions = new List<Questions>();
```

In addition you will need to insert Question objects into the List to have something to access.

```
this.Questions.Add(new Question());
```

I think you may be trying to access the list like you would an array, which is incorrect.

Edit - Based on your code changes, I *think* your saying that each time you add a new question, your xml file gets a list of all existing questions each time, with the new question appended to the end, so something like:

In
Q1
Out
Q1

In
Q2
Out
Q1
Q1
Q2

In
Q3
Out
Q1
Q1
Q2
Q1
Q2
Q3

If that's correct, you'll need to change how your file i/o works. You want to create a new xml document, not append to the existing.

Comment: The problem is i already have another button to add a new xml document as intented (a holder to be more spefic), its possible to add many holders with several questions . It actually has to fit those question into it. And yeah it get something like that. The questions get added to the proper holder. But for example the questionText gets added with each next node, Q1 for the first then Q2 Q2, Q3 Q3 Q3 wich all except one are just empty nodes. Pretty much what you ment i think.

Comment: Is the sample XML after calling SaveHolder twice?

Comment: Is it possible to get a small working sample with the problem, and an full example xml file on pastebin? I can't copy & paste out of SO without the format getting mangled beyond belief.

Comment: Ok will do but it will not be in english then. But it should you give a clear picture whats going on i think. Appreciate it asawyer!

Comment: That looks great, and the language thing won't really hurt to badly but I can't copy & paste out of SO, it removes all the line ends, so I just get a messy glob when I paste. Can you put it here http://pastebin.com/ so I can copy it properly?

Comment: It was said before, you never seem to initialize our `Enquete.Vragen` property. In the constructor of the `Enquete` class, add `this.Vragen = new List<Vraag>();`.

Comment: I have it running in LINQPad now, but as far as I can tell, it seems to be working the way you want it to.

Comment: Each question(vraag) only should have one questiontext (vraagTekst). But every time i add a question it add ones extra (same goes for every value in the foreach loop. The foreach in SaveEnquete is the thing thats giving these wrong inputs.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're asking, but I can at least address the error of the object reference.

`List<>` is a reference type, and reference types are by default `null`.  So this:

```
public List<Question> Questions{ get; set; }
```

will default to `null` when the class is instantiated.  For reference types in your class members to have a default value, you'll need to instantiate them in your constructor:

```
public Holder()
{
    this.Questions = new List<Question>();
}
```

Comment: The Question object gets filled with values in the other class and then it gets added to the Holder. Its in the other class i wish to acces this question object if this makes any more sence. The method in the class i am trying to acces it already has the Holder given in the constructor.

Comment: @TakLee: I'm afraid it's still unclear.  Can you show us the actual classes, how you're populating the `Questions` member, how you're reading from it, and where the error is?

Comment: Ok will do in a min tryign to illustrate

Comment: @TakLee I updated my answer, the question is still very vague though, could you maybe show us exactly what your input/output looks like?